# Concatenating part of multi-dimensional matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, reshape

I am dealing with image data and I have 240 images each consisting of 5 channel contributions of size 231 by 384. This matrix is now of size (240,231,384,5) and I would like to have this as (231*240,384,5). I can't 'reshape' it without distorting the data. How do I do this?

Comment: Why not just `reshape(data, 240*231,384,5)`?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do that ? The means of the first dimension mean nothing after ?

Comment: @Maria: What do you expect to be the output of M(2,:,:,:)? Second row of the first picture or first row of the second picture?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess at what you are trying to do

```
test = [1:16]; % sample data
test1 = reshape(test, 4, 4); % rearrange to 4x4
% this has a vertical arrangement which is prob not what you have

[m, n] = size(test1); % get dims
r = 2; % horizontal width / numb of cols
% this prob closer to what you have
test2 = test1(:,1:r)'  % flip to horizontal order
test3 = reshape(test2, m*r, 1) % rearrange to vertical
```

Comment: As Daniel R has said, please include the example output you are looking for. It is not clear what you are trying to do. What distortion are talking about? What does your data look like? Can you give us a smaller portion of your code with the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Given a matrix:

```
n1 = 240; n2 = 231; n3 = 384; n4 = 5;
A = randn(n1, n2, n3, n4);
```

I guess the solution you are seeking is either as suggested by Luis above:

```
B = reshape(A, n1 * n2, n3, n4);
```

or

```
C = reshape(permute(A, [2 1 3 4]), n1 * n2, n3, n4);
```

Otherwise you have to explain better what your problem is.